# Make [gdk] a synonym of [google-gdk]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

[gdk](/questions/tagged/gdk) and [google-gdk](/questions/tagged/google-gdk) both refer to the [Google Glass Development Kit](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/). I think these tags should be synonyms with [google-gdk](/questions/tagged/google-gdk) as the master tag.

Comment: `[gdk]` also designates [another library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDK), maybe it could be repurposed towards it? There already are mistagged questions, apparently.

Comment: It actually looks like Google attempted to take over a tag that doesn't belong to it. There are only 4 questions that are also tagged with something Google-related. I reverted the wiki changes for now.

Comment: Yes there is a "GIMP Development Kit" (GDK) that exists.  While I would lean toward using gdk -> google-gdk, perhaps ensuring there is no synonym at the moment is best (if the GIMP Development Kit" is still quite active.